# Decimal minutes

Tags: php, time, decimal

Hi  not sure if this is the right forum for this but does anyone know the formula for converting decimal time in to hours and minutes ?

IE 1.4 = 1hr 24mins

thanks for any help and sorry if its the wrong forum

Comment: Not sure what you intend on using this for, but if you're using this to describe how long ago something happened from the current point in time, take a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11/how-do-i-calculate-relative-time/501415#501415

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
$decTime = 1.4;
$hour = floor($decTime);
$min = round(60*($decTime-$hour));
```

Comment: Note the round on the minutes. I had it as a floor and some of the time display wasn't showing correctly by a minute. So annoying! Thanks guys!

Answer (score 4):

Simply take the decimal portion of the hours and multiply by 60 for the number of minutes.

In your example `.4 (the decimal portion of 1.4) * 60 = 24 minutes`

So if you need to do it in code, subtract the [floor](http://php.net/manual/en/function.floor.php) of the original number from the original number to get the decimal portion.

Answer (score 2):

Hours: floor( decimal )
Minutes: round( ( decimal * 60 ) mod 60 )

[James](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2648117/decimal-minutes/2648132#2648132) is right about the rounding. I forgot to account for that. Adjusted.

Answer (score 1):

Floor the number to get how many hours.  Number - floored value [the decimal] * 60 = minutes [round it after]